# How to read object custom properties from a TMXObjectGroup?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, tmx

When constructing a `TMXTiledMap` instance with Cocos2D-X, how can one access an object custom properties ?

I can see that [TMXObjectGroup](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.3/d4/dfa/classcocos2d_1_1_t_m_x_object_group.html) provides a `getObject` method

```
ValueMap getObject (const std::string &objectName) const
```

but how do I access unnamed objects within a loop ? There is a `getObjects()` method which returns a vector of `Value` but what are the values in that case?

Comment: Did you get the answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

they are a `ValueMap` (`std::unordered_map<std::string, Value>`) of the properties for that object:

```
auto& objects = group->getObjects();
for (auto &obj : objects) {
    auto &properties = obj.asValueMap();
    cc_log(properties["type"].asString());
}
```